# Architecture of a company-wide Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

In our company we use Google spreadsheets heavily. I would like to automate some things, for instance every minute I would like to call our bank's API and save all the new transactions into a spreadsheet.

What I'm missing in the official documentation is some major architecture best practices.

First part of the question: Who should be the owner/runner of such user-neutral company-wide script? I would not like to bind it to my personal account. I want it to run seamlessly even after I leave the company some day. Is some artificial technical user needed?

If it makes any difference we plan on moving to team drives in future.

Second part of the question: I would like the scripts to have persistent storages (in the example above - for the record of transactions). I'm considering to be a rule that every script is bound to a spreadsheet which acts as its data store. Is it a good idea?

Comment: In general, for Apps Script projects that are used by more than one person, and/or it would be very bad if something ever happened to the script, you should use a "stand alone" Apps Script file.  You can back-up an Apps Script file just by right clicking the file in Drive, and choosing "Download."  The best option to make code available to multiple users is by using an Add-on.  An Add-on does NOT need to be published to the public.  And it can be published domain wide.  You should be able to set up a user account that is for generic use inside the domain.

Comment: But your organization should have written documentation of how to access everyone's account.  That's not really an Apps Script issue or a file issue.  That's basically a Human Resources responsibility.  As far as persistent storage, it depends on whether on one category of data is going to be over 9k bytes.  It that is the case, then I'd store the data outside of the script.  9k is the limit for any one "property" in Properties Service.

Comment: Libraries are not secure, if you want to keep any user from obtaining the code.  Probably extremely few people know how to get the code out of a library, but for anyone with some time and motivation, they could probably find out.

Answer (score 2):

I generally recommend that clients provide me with an "artificial technical user", as you say, to keep that owner alive and away from my personal account. Which also avoids using up my daily quota especially for regular triggers.

I'd avoid binding the scripts to a GSheet as you'll then get issues with potentially using GitHub or creating add-ons in the future. I generally make all scripts in a separate library ([Bruce McPherson did various tests and never found a performance hit](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/libraryloadspeed)) and then link them with a very small script to a script contained in a GSheet if needs be. This allow eases separate development whilst the script is being used live.

GSheets do provide a fair amount of storage (2 million cells) but if you reach that - and the sheets do tend to slow down - take a look at using Firebase for which you get 1GB free and there is [a great Firebase library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase).

There are various general recommendations for Apps Script development. I link a few [here](http://www.andrewroberts.net/google-apps-script/google-apps-script-development-best-practices/).

Happy scripting!

Comment: I have discovered a Google term "service account". Can it serve as the artificial account we were talking about? An do you use it or do you use a full blown Google user account?

Comment: A full blown account.